# How do I stop Key Error on df.sort_values()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I can't seem to find an answer to this particular error. I am trying to do a simple sort on my dataframe but every time I do it gives a Key Error. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

scores = [97, 91, 95, 88, 67, 65]
weights = [.5, .2, .1, .1, .05, .05]

##Put this into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Scores','Weights'])
df.Scores = scores
df.Weights = weights

df.sort_values(df['Scores'])
```

Every time I run this I get:

```
KeyError: 0    97
1    91
2    95
3    88
4    67
5    65
Name: Scores, dtype: int64
```

Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -** In case you want to sort entire `DataFrame` based on a specific column, should fill the parameter as follows :

```py
df.sort_values(by='Scores')
```

```
   Scores  Weights
5      65     0.05
4      67     0.05
3      88     0.10
1      91     0.20
2      95     0.10
0      97     0.50
```

**2 -** In case you only want to sort `Series`, you should write it as follows :

```py
df['Scores'].sort_values()
```

```
5    65
4    67
3    88
1    91
2    95
0    97
Name: Scores, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Such a simple solution for a problem I've been trying to solve for an hour.